# Combining Django Q Object Lookups into One Filter

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am having an issue with Q object lookups, whereas when user searches for multiple terms, the search returns nothing unless all terms are in the same object.

If you go to https://www.soledadmemorial.com/plaques and search for `David S Hackley` the search returns nothing, but if you search for just `David S` you get a result.

I've tried to combine the filter like `(Q(first_name__icontains=query), Q(last_name__icontains=query))` but just get an error.  Below is my current code. That works without combining searches form multiple objects.

```
...
if query:
   queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
     Q(first_name__icontains=query) |
     Q(last_name__icontains=query) |
     Q(branch__icontains=query) |
     Q(rank__icontains=query) |
     Q(group__group_name__icontains=query) |
     Q(veteran__name__icontains=query)
).distinct()
...
```

Comment: I don't get how you mean combine search from multiple objects

Comment: What is the query actually generated by Django, and what do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[icontains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) gets translated into database as

```
ILIKE '%query_text%'
```

When you are searching for David S it finds it as first_name.

You are not having

```
ILIKE '%David S Hackley%'
```

as any of your columns in database so icontains wont do it here.

You should consider using [SearchVector](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchvector) ( postgres )  or even [haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/)

Comment: Thank you.  I up-voted it because you explained what was happening instead of just offering a link to another method.

Comment: Edited for small fix as it is icontains it uses ILIKE